# ican't run codeIginter in ubuntu 11.10 under root permission

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to run codeIginter php Freamework under ubuntu, I add www-data group to root, also phpMyAdmin won't work it says "The requested URL /phpMyAdmin was not found on this server.",

- i loged as root because all help to add another users to www-data wasn't help me.
- i removed/instal agian apache so many times but no solution.
- the localhost work fine.

please help quick ...

Comment: Are "coz" and "plz" the first words people learn in English? Because it seems many people put more care in writing those two then the rest of their question

Comment: You should avoid to ask two different things in the same question, it is against the StackOverflow rules.

Comment: @Manee.O.H problem solved??

Comment: Yes. I asked this question when i started learning PHP under Linux.

Comment: This solved by avoiding mistakes in apache/phpmyadmin installation. also by going back to really knowing what's going on in users permission (www-data).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why phpmyadmin doesn't work might be this: during the phpmyadmin installation there is a screen where you have to select the server: **first** you should to select apache using SPACEBAR and **only then** you press return, but 99% of the people don't get the spacebar thing because it's not intuitive. In case you didn't get it as well, open your /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and insert the following line:

```
INCLUDE /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Comment: Also, this is not strictly a programming topic, you should use Ask Ubuntu instead of StackOverflow. Ask Ubuntu is part of the Stack Exchange network, so when you create a new account it is automatically linked to your existing StackOverflow account.